# Converting a string[] into a string then split into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, split

I need help creating a loop which splits strings. So far I have the code below.

```
    System.out.println("*FILE HAS BEEN LOCATED*");
    System.out.println("*File contains: \n");
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
      lines.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

    String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    String str_array = Arrays.toString(arr);

    String[] arraysplit;
    arraysplit = str_array.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<arraysplit.length; i++)
    {
        arraysplit[i] = arr[i].trim();
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

an example of one of the strings would be

```
        Firstname : Lastname : age
```

I want it to split the string into another array that looks like:

```
        Firstname
        Lastname
        age
```

I still encounter an error when running the code, it seems as though when I convert the array to a string, it puts commas in the string and therefore it causes problems  as I'm trying to split the string on : not ,

image:
[image: IMAGE, I've circled where the commas are within the converted array string]

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Could it be that you are making things too complex?  `"Firstname : Lastname : age".split("\\s*:\\s*")` should give you the result you want.

Comment: This question still makes no sense at all. ___You___ call `Arrays.toString(arr)` which clearly and obviously writes each array item into one String using a `,` as the separator and yet you expect it doesn't behave like it is documented. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue** : you are using the old array `arr` to display values and `arraysplit` will have resultant values of `split` method so you need to apply `trim()` on `arraysplit`'s elements and assign back the elements to same indexes

```
String[] arraysplit;
arraysplit = str_array.split(":");

for (int i=0; i<arraysplit.length; i++)
{
    arraysplit[i] = arraysplit[i].trim();
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ has values with spaces
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}

System.out.println(arraysplit[i]);
```

---

To simplify solution without (list to array and array to string complication)

1.) Create array of length as `sizeOfList * 3`

2.) `split` the list element using `\\s*:\\s*`

3.) Use array copy with `j`as index of resultant array to keep the track of the array index

```
    String result[] = new String [lines.size()*3];
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy(lines.get(0).split("\\s*:\\s*"), 0, result, j, 3);
        j+=3;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

---

You can use [`regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html) `str_array.split("\\s*:\\s*");` where

`\\s*:\\s*` : `\\s*` mean zero or more spaces then `:` character then zero or more spaces

```
arraysplit = str_array.split("\\s*:\\s*");
// just use values of arraysplit
```

Comment: Please look at the image I have attached to my question, as I still encounter an error when running the code, it seems as though when I convert the array to a string, it puts commas in the string and therefore it causes problems  as I'm trying to split the string on : not ,

Comment: @rxbert is there is chance that your input can have any special character other than alphabets and numbers? if no then easy way is `arraysplit = str_array.split("\\s*\\W\\s*");`

Answer (score 2):

Split using this regex `\s*:\s*`

```
String[] arraysplit = str_array.split("\\s*:\\s*");
```

details :

- `\s*` zero or more spaces
- followed by lateral character `:`
- followed by  `\s*` zero or more spaces

---

#### regex demo

Comment: Please look at the image I have attached to my question, as I still encounter an error when running the code, it seems as though when I convert the array to a string, it puts commas in the string and therefore it causes problems as I'm trying to split the string on : not ,